# KsqlException when launching ksql-server-start /etc/ksql/ksqlserver.properties

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

We are setting up ksql using Docker. But it throws

```
Exception in thread "main" io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlException: Unable to check broker compatibility against a broker without any topics
```

This is the content of /etc/ksql/ksqlserver.properties file:

```
bootstrap.servers=0e234781853f:9092,5e9fbcd03294:9092,c48090cb8e79:9092
ksql.command.topic.suffix=commands_2018-01-10-022223
listeners=http://0.0.0.0:8080
commit.interval.ms=1000
auto.offset.reset=earliest
```

"0e234781853f:9092,5e9fbcd03294:9092,c48090cb8e79:9092" are the kafka broker containers. We can produce message to the brokers from the ksql container.

We use "confluentinc/ksql-cli:0.3" dockerhub image as a base. So, is there any wrong from my setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the log message, it seems that you need to create at least a topic on of your broker first, e.g. using command line:

`kafka-topics --zookeeper <your_zookeeper> --create --topic test --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as David Cheung said the compatibility check need at least one topic in your kafka cluster. We will remove this requirement in the next version.